# Accessing Redis Class outside of laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am listening to a socket of tracker device and I have created a php class in the public folder, and in that file I am accessing the Redis class to publish the data to server, but I am getting the following error:

```
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\socket5\public\socket-server.php(38): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('publish', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\socket5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 218

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\socket5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:
218
```

This the error I am getting. And this is what I am doing:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as Facade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
 Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode($data));
```

This is how I am listening to socket:

```
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://IP_ADDRESS:4000", $errno, $errorMessage);
if ($server === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
}
else {
    $i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if($i == 0) {
            $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);
        }
        if ($client) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $message= fread($client, 80000);
                echo $message;
                $response=pack("H*","01");
                fwrite($client, $response);
                $i++;
            }
            else {
                $message= fread($client, 80000);
                $data = $message;
                echo $message;
                if(trim($message) == "") {
                    fclose($client);
                    $i = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $hexData = bin2hex($message);
                    $decoder = new TeltonikaFmParser\TcpDecoder();
                    $original_data = $decoder->decodeData($hexData);
                    echo $json_string = json_encode($original_data);
                    $data = [
                        'event' => 'UserSignedUp',
                        'data' => $original_data
                    ];
                    Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode($data));
                    //insertintodatabase($json_string);
                    fclose($client);
                    $i = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched for this but cant find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If someone can help in how to listen to a socket within laravel that would be great too.

Comment: Running Facades outside laravel requires a lot of work on your side; I would create a route & run my code without creating something outside the app itself (it's easier)

Comment: The issue I am facing is that I need to listen to a external socket which laravel do not support by default. This is the reason I have to create a listener outside of laravel.

Comment: How are you listening to this external socket ? Laravel uses PHP, if you can do it outside Laravel then you should be able to do it inside it too ... Please provide some code examples to see what's the problem

Comment: I am running an external script for a socket server. Basically it is a socket listening server. Let me update the Question for you. I am using a socket stream.

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: The code you provided doesn't belong to the public directory & it shouldn't be run using the webserver, you should be using the terminal to run it ... And I am thinking you can make it into its own artisan command https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan

Comment: Yes thats true I am running it using terminal. Let me see the docs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for giving me the direction, This solved my issue I have made that a command and it is working perfect. Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped, I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't belong to the public directory & it shouldn't be run using the web-server, you should be using the terminal to run it ... And I am thinking you can make it into its own artisan command

[Check Laravel's Artisan Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan)